# Yolo V4 detects twice to one object

Tags: object-detection, yolo, darknet, yolov4

I am training darknet/yolov4 for object detection. When I trained the model and look at the demo, yolov4 detects two objects for one object. How can I fix that problem.

[[image: Double detected image]

Comment: It seem like you retrain your demo using previous network configuration.

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix multiple predictions is to increase the threshold. Try including the `-thresh 0.5` in your test command. This will allow not ignore predictions with a score less than 0.5.